# SQLite Query testing for multiple row matches

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I am a bit stuck trying to query this:
Find all Customers that have ordered the same as Customer Number 250

Schema for database:

```
Customers(
customerNumber INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY
);

Orders(
orderNumber INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY
customerNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (customerNumber) REFERENCES Customers
);

OrderDetails (
  orderNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  productCode TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (orderNumber, productCode),
  FOREIGN KEY (productCode) REFERENCES Products
);
```

I figured the query:

```
select DISTINCT customerNumber
  FROM Orders Natural 
  JOIN OrderDetails
 WHERE productCode NOT IN (
    select productCode
    FROM Orders NATURAL JOIN OrderDetails
    WHERE customerNumber = 219
)    
order by customerNumber;
```

would be correct but it returns nothing, so clearly I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: 250 or 219 ...?

Comment: ah sorry 250, mixed some numbers, it should be 250 in the query

Comment: also that select query makes me think there are more rules than just if customerNumber = 250

Comment: So if customer 250 ordered products A, B, and C, and customer 300 ordered A and B and customer 400 ordered A, B, and C, and customer 500 ordered A, B, C, and D. Which customers do you want to show? Is it about at least one product in common? All 250's products? Exactly the same products?

Comment: 400 and 500 would then be shown, the customer numbers of all customers who have bought A, B and C but not necessarily just those products.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please don't vandalize / remove your question once it has a useful answer, it may be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need all customer those are order all the product that 250 order or more than 250 but have same product , so tried with conditional aggregation

```
   select customerNumber
      FROM Orders o
      JOIN OrderDetails od 
     on o.orderNumber =od.orderNumber 
     WHERE od.productCode IN (
        select productCode
        FROM Orders o
       JOIN OrderDetails od 
       on o.orderNumber =od.orderNumber
        WHERE customerNumber = 250
    )    
     group by customerNumber
    having count(distinct productCode )>= 
        (select count(distinct productCode )
        FROM Orders o
       JOIN OrderDetails od 
       on o.orderNumber =od.orderNumber
        WHERE customerNumber = 250)
```

Comment: FYI you have an uneven number of parentheses in this code.